# Calling `_.debounce` inside a watcher not working

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

consider the following example: https://codesandbox.io/s/nuxt-playground-forked-rld4j?file=/pages/index.vue

I tried to make a minimal example that involves my general use case. That's the reason for the odd format of the data. Type 000 or 111 and you can see how it gradually searches through the data.

Basically it generates a lot of data (I actually want to have more than that) but you already notice a drop in performance. Now I thought I could start improving the performance by debouncing my watcher. You can see that in line 58 in the above example. It's commented out because. You can comment line 57 out and add the debouncing to see that it doesn't work.

Here's the code of the above example:

```html
    <template>
      <div>
        <input type="text" v-model="searchString" />
        SearchString: {{ searchString }}
        <div v-for="(items, index) in this.filteredPosts" :key="items[0]">
          <div v-for="item in items" :key="item">
            {{ item }}
          </div>
          <br />
        </div>
      </div>
    </template>
    
    <script>
    import _ from "lodash";
    
    export default {
      async asyncData() {
        // Just generate some random data
        let animals = ["dog", "cat", "fish", "computer", "c++"];
        // At this point the posts aren't filtered. We just call
        // them filtered because we use this variable name to
        // render and we want the variable filteredPosts available
        // as early as possible.
        let filteredPosts = [];
        const N = 1000;
        const M = 6;
        for (let i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
          let tmpSubArray = [String(i)];
          for (let j = 0; j < M; ++j) {
            tmpSubArray.push(i + " " + j);
          }
          filteredPosts.push(tmpSubArray);
        }
    
        return { filteredPosts };
      },
      data() {
        return {
          searchString: "",
          posts: [],
        };
      },
      watch: {
        searchString() {
          // If this.posts is empty, which is only in the very
          // beginning the case, store a copy of the original
          // posts (which at this point are stored in
          // this.filteredPosts )
          // => from now one this.posts is the original data which
          // won't get changed ever and this.filteredPosts is being
          // changed.
          if (this.posts.length === 0) {
            this.posts = this.filteredPosts;
          }
    
          this.filteredPosts = this.filterByValue();
          /* _.debounce(function () {
            console.log("debounce");
            this.filteredPosts = this.filterByValue();
          });
          */
        },
      },
      methods: {
        filterByValue() {
          // Get searchString
          const searchString = this.searchString.toLowerCase();
    
          // Loop over all posts
          let foo = this.posts.filter((items) => {
            return items.some((item) => {
              if (item.toLowerCase().includes(searchString)) {
                return true;
              }
              return false;
            });
          });
          return foo;
        },
      },
    };
    </script>
```

Now I fail to see why it wouldn't work. Can someone point me to the issue? Please point out all other issues if there are any. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the lag in component rendering when increasing the number of items, is not caused by filtering function, but are directly related to the rendering of DOM components, and this is not solved by debouncing the filtering, but by decreasing the number of rendered items. For ex., in the below codesandbox, I sliced the rendered items to the first 20 results, and you can test that even without debouncing it has no lag even with very large initial data. So think in that direction (lazy rendering of elements).

Second, if still you need to debounce the filtering, then the implementation of debounce is not correct.

> The _.debounce() method of Function in lodash is used to create a
> debounced function which delays the given func until after the stated
> wait time in milliseconds have passed since the last time this
> debounced function was called.

So, basically `_.debounce` create a new (debounced) function from an existing one.

```
debouncedFunc = _.debounce(existingFunc, timeout)
```

By calling in watcher

```
_.debounce(function () {
        this.filteredPosts = this.filterByValue();
      });
```

you are creating a new debounced function every time the watcher is triggered, but never call it.

The correct implementation involve the following:

```
// Having some function that need debouncing

existingFunc(){
  // code
}

// Creating a debounced version from the existing one

const deboncedFunc = _.debounce(existingFunc, 1000)

// Calling the debounced version

debouncedFunc()
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-goldwasser-bj2sy?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue

Comment: I see. Thanks for the additional comment about lazy loading and even including an example. :)

Comment: Why did you use `mounted()` instead of `asyncData()`? Also note that you basically only have `N=10'000` because of the error thrown.

Comment: I didn't use asyncData() because I have not included Nuxt in the example. about the error, I didn't noticed it, thanks

Answer (score 2):

`debounce` doesn't work the way it's expected to.

`debounce` returns debounced function. If a function isn't called, `debounce(...)` is a no-op.

Debounced function needs to be created beforehand, not in the context it's supposed to be debounced, it would be impossible for `debounce` to postpone function calls when used like that because it creates a new debounced function each time it's called.

It should be:

```
  data() {
    return {
      ...
      debouncedFilterByValue: _.debounce(this.filterByValue)
    }
  },
  watch: {
    searchString() {
      ...
      this.filteredPosts = this.debouncedFilterByValue();
    },
  },
```