# Debounce axios interceptor instance with lodash?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, debouncing

I'm using a state prop called network busy status to toggle elements in the UI.

Because the status can change very quickly back and forth, my spinner looks like it's on crack.

Is there an easy way, using lodash _.debounce to throttle this block of code?

```
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: environment.CUSTOM_BASE_URL,
});

instance.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
  store.commit("setNetworkBusyStatus", true);
  return config;
});

instance.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) => {
    store.commit("setNetworkBusyStatus", false); // wait for X ms because this is going to get set back to true in a millisecond.
    return response;
  },
  (error) => {
    if ([401, 403].includes(error.response.status)) {
      store.commit("delUserData");
      router.push("/login");
    }
    return Promise.reject(error);
  },
);
```

Comment: It's likely a spinner that needs to implement debouncing because the problem is its visual representation. The interceptor just does its job and keeps setNetworkBusyStatus up to date.

Comment: @EstusFlask Thanks. It's actually just an SVG animated with CSS. It looks fine in many instances but few, not because its `v-if="networkBusyStatus"` is rerendering it rapidly, depending on if I'm making lots of quick network calls. I agree the whole thing could be refactored to be smarter. Just looking for a quick fix.

Comment: It would be `const reqInterceptor = debounce((config) => { ... }) ... instance.interceptors.request.use(reqInterceptor)` but I expect it to be faulty because. req and res interceptors aren't guaranteed to run in order and will mess the status up. A proper quick fix is to update spinner state inside `networkBusyStatus` watcher with debounced watch function, or setter method. The latter will be very close to the question I've just encountered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67909124/calling-debounce-inside-a-watcher-not-working/67909967 .

Comment: Also loader state is simplistic and will be faulty from time to time with concurrent requests. Boolean state isn't enough, it should count requests and responses

Comment: @EstusFlask That worked. I just shamelessly added a short timeout in the setNetworkBusyStatus setter.

Answer (score 0):

#### you do this

```js
import _ from 'lodash'
// vuex code
mutations:{
   setNetworkBusyStatus= _.debounce(function(){
    xxxx
})
}
// axios code
instance.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) => {
    store.commit("setNetworkBusyStatus", false); // wait for X ms because this is going to get set back to true in a millisecond.
    return response;
  },
  (error) => {
    if ([401, 403].includes(error.response.status)) {
      store.commit("delUserData");
      router.push("/login");
    }
    return Promise.reject(error);
  },
);
```